# Android 4.2 Title Bar over Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, titlebar

In my aplication only on 4.2 devices do that:

[image]

My activity manifest:

```
<activity
   android:name=".CatalogListActivity"
   android:label="@string/lbl_catalog"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
</activity>
```

My onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cataloglist_activity);

    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(null);

    initControls();

    checkCatalogs();

}
```

Comment: Can you post cataloglist_activity? You're not settings fitsSystemWindows to false or something, are you?

Comment: @kcoppock no! Other activitys are working normal, but only that this is happening. (I'm trying post but stackoverflow saying alot of code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug

the previous activity (which was a splash screen), the theme was set as fullscreen. For some reason, when I called the other activity by intent, the bug described happened.

What I did:

I changed the manifest to:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

and added in onCreate of the SplashScreen:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Thanks!